# A big logical mess

Tags: rebus, physics, proof-without-words, circuitry

I found a drawing under a stack of books in my house. It looked like a logical circuit diagram, so I decided to make it. I assumed that I was allowed to put anything in the boxes with the question marks.

And guess what? The drawing was correct, no matter what I put in the question mark boxes.

> What was the drawing saying, and why was it correct?

**Bonus:** Thinking about it more, it also helped me with my physics homework. How?

Here's the drawing!

[image: Drawing]

---

<sub>Not a true story</sub>

Comment: By any chance, is the bottom line's
[**b**-looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGJkj.png)
symbol
[Wien's blackbody radiation constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law)?
In other words, is it a **b** or a **6** or a $\bf\delta$ or something else altogether?

Comment: @humn The symbol isn't $\delta$ or a b, and no, I made it up. But you're welcome to make it into a placemat if you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing seems to be that

> there are only *five* (not six) connections between the two boxes on the right; some information is necessarily lost on the way around.

So perhaps

> the yellow thing at the bottom is an LED or similar, and the annotation says "this-thing-on-the-left not lit-up for-all inputs". In other words, whatever you put into the boxes, it can't arrange for the signals coming out of them all to equal the signals going in.

I suppose I should say explicitly that

> the circuitry at bottom left is testing exactly that, as described in humn's answer.

It's not clear to me, though,

> what the rightmost part of the annotation means. If the rightmost symbol were a 6, it could signify something like "... input of size 6", but boboquack has already indicated that it isn't. [EDITED to add: oops, no he hasn't; in fact he conspicuously didn't, and it turns out it was a 6 and meant pretty much exactly that.]

As for the application in physics,

> there are a number of things in physics with this sort of flavour. It might for instance point at Liouville's theorem on conservation of phase-space volume, or maybe something to do with the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: The v.6 is just to show that the $\forall$ corresponds to all 6 inputs, not just 1. The thing I had in mind was the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Ah! I thought you'd said it wasn't a 6, but in fact I see you pointedly *didn't* say that :-). My apologies for the misreading.

Answer (score 10):

The circuit alone rigorously tests
one ironic aphorism
and another time-tested adage.

> “The more things change, the more they stay the same.”
>  –
>  [Jean-Baptiste Alphonse
>    Karr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Baptiste_Alphonse_Karr#Life)
>  
>  
>  “Some things never change.”
>  –
>  [Isaac Newton
>   and others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law)

**A specific scientific hypothesis for the overall rebus:**

> The overall momentum of a (closed) system cannot be changed,
>  regardless of any changes in its components.

**Interpretation**

The circuit has an input at the top whose components
<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
 get copied and split to the right.

> The right branch undergoes two arbitrary
>  transformations — change
>  and more change — before
>  returning for comparison against the original input.

The legend along the right of the picture identifies
crossings
<sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub>
as
[no-contact
 crossovers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_diagram#/media/File:Wire_Crossover_Symbols_for_Circuit_Diagrams.png),
square
<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
components as
[XNOR gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate#Symbols),
and triangular/**A**-shaped
<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
components as
[AND gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate#Symbols).

> An XNOR gate, despite any mumbo-jumbo, merely tests equality.
>  The AND gates collect the component-wise equality comparisons
>  to see if everything matches and nothing changed.

The bottom line *could* be
(**incorrectly**, informs the puzzle’s poser)
transcribed and interpreted as follows:

> [image]
>  
>  “There, on the left, the total change is nil”:
>    
>  $\displaystyle 0 ~ = \!\sum_\textsf{all inputs} \kern-.5em {\sf input} \cdot \delta$
>  
>  
>  Loosely speaking,
>   $\delta$ can represent a type of change to be measured
>  and a dot product can represent a result of measurement
>  (a projection onto the direction of measurement).

Comment: Look carefully at the right branch. There is more detail there than you have yet seen. Anyways, the symbol between the not gate and the $\forall$ is not $\Sigma$, and the last symbol is not $\delta$. (I may be bad at drawing, but I'm not quite that bad ... yet)

Comment: Thanks for the guardrails, @boboquack.  Now I notice a change between the changes on the right. 

Comment: Hope you can get it now...

Comment: In response to your comment on the lair, no, part of it has been right, it's just the rebus at the bottom that's not quite, which is tripping you up.